Is it possible to reconstruct a triangle from orthocenter, incenter and centroid?
Given the  orthocenter, incenter and centroid Can the original triangle be reconstructed with compass and straight line? (assuming orthocenter, incenter and centroid are threee different points )
I thought of this problem when I posted This question and after more than a week thinking and trying I gave up and decided to ask here.
Maybe one can find an algebraic solution by finding the coordinates of the orthocenter and incenter  knowing the  coordinates  of the vertices of the triangle and then one have three (ugly and nonlinear) equations in three unknowns so it is possible to solve for the vertices, but is it possible to reconstruct the triangle with compass and straight line ?
If it is not possible what extra information needed to reconstruct the triangle?

The triangle is not even uniquely determined. You can easily have equilateral triangles of different sizes but the same center.

@DavidGao I meant the the three points given are different. I think the triangle can be uniquely determined in any other case

Perhaps. I don’t know. I’d suggest actually writing down those equations in any case. If the answer is no, then an algebraic approach is likely necessary.

@DavidGao Finding the equation of two orthogonal lines and finding their intersection took two pages of calculations and I can't trust myself not making some mistake there, the coordinates of the incenter  seem to be a nightmare to calculate.

An online search easily finds all the formulas for you. For example, here’s one for incenter: https://byjus.com/maths/incenter-of-a-triangle/

(The same formula is also in the Wikipedia article on incenters.)

@DavidGao The formula is still ugly and nonlinear, I couldn't find the for the orthocenter.

If you meant three different points you should specify that in the question, not just as a comment.

This has an answer here. Note that from orthocenter $H$ and centroid $G$ one can construct circumcenter $O$ as $O=G+{1\over2}(G-H)$.
